# centos docker:Error while pulling image

Tags: docker

I'm installing docker on CentOS 7 and i have this issue :

> $ proxychains4 docker run hello-world

```
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.so
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: tls: oversized record received with length 26992.
```

**the docker message :**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:20:01 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:20:01 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**the centos message:**

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 20 12:24:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Does it work without proxychains? What is proxychains doing in this case and why is it required? I'm guessing this is an issue with the way proxychains interacts with Docker.

Comment: Proxychains  is a  terminal proxy .And without it ,the same error happens again.  Now I think the error message "tls: oversized record received with length 26992."  is the main problem.